# Changing default locations on Git Bash

Tags: git, github, repository, git-bash

I am new to using Git Bash and Git Hub. Upon installing Bash, I accepted all of the default settings. In doing so, made my network drive the default directory. I will be using this offline and need to change the default directory to my local drive. I have tried to change the location path of GitBash to the local drive but did this did not work. How can I change this? Also, is there any alterations that need to be made to the GitHub account?

Comment: What about doing a clean re-install of Git bash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the default location for Git Bash on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671461/how-do-i-change-the-default-location-for-git-bash-on-windows)

Answer (score 22):

In my case I had to take the following steps to change the default startup directory of the Git Bash in Windows:

**1)** Right click on the Git Bash icon in your Windows Start menu and select Properties. In Windows 10 you may have to right click on Git Bash -> More -> Open file location -> Right click on the shortcut -> Properties
**2)** In the `Start in` field, paste the path to your desired folder, e.g. `D:\git`.
**3)** Remove `--cd-to-home` from the `Target` field.

Comment: followed the same steps Not working for me any idea, thoughts

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the shortcut to Git Bash in order to specify the starting directory. This is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32125911/24874).

Alternatively you can create a file called `.bashrc` in your home directory. That script is executed when the shell starts (rc stands for run-commands), so you can make that file `cd` into whatever directory you like.

Comment: @siluverukirankumar why not? You should have write permission to your home directory.

Comment: I am able to create another file but I am not able to create .bashrc file

Comment: @siluverukirankumar what error does it give you? Does the file already exist?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it from CMD:

```
start /D "path_target_on_windows_here" git_bash_path\git-bash.exe
```

It is useful for configuring a shortcut command on Notepad++ :]

Answer (score 0):

Try creating `.bashrc`, refer to this solution

https://shawnhymel.com/576/quick-tip-changing-default-directory-of-git-bash/