# How can I see all the options that can be passed to git-bash.exe?

Tags: git-bash

I can see that from the start menu shortcut the `git-bash.exe` command starts with `--cd-to-home` option. What other options can be passed to it, and how can I list them?

Comment: Seems like this is better fit for [Super User](https://superuser.com)

Comment: There you have a similar question => [https://superuser.com/q/1104567/322291](https://superuser.com/q/1104567/322291)

Comment: And here you have another question, about something similar => [https://stackoverflow.com/q/19916670/2954267](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19916670/2954267)