# Open new Git Bash terminal with given commands

Tags: windows, bash, shell, git-bash

I'm trying to write an alias to open several new Bash terminals and run a given command in each one. From this question: [How to launch a Git Bash window with particular working directory using a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916670/how-to-launch-a-git-bash-window-with-particular-working-directory-using-a-script) I've got an alias that opens multiple windows in the right folder, but I can't figure out how to get each window to run any commands without typing them in manually after.

This is what I've got so far:

```
alias openterminals='(cd C:/folder/one && start sh --login); (cd C:/folder/two && start sh --login); (C:/folder/three && start sh --login);'
```

Comment: @Tabitha_Hastie `sh` is taking `--login` as an arg. it should be possible to pass something like `-c ls` as well to make a terminal open and list files. I cant make it work, though. You could try a .bashrc which does pwd and runs the commands you want depending on where it is run from.