# Create a shortcut in SendTo that opens git-bash.exe

Tags: powershell, git-bash

How can I create a shortcut, specifically in `SendTo` (i.e. not on the right-click context menu itself) that opens `git-bash.exe` in a folder I have right-clicked on. There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386657/how-to-add-a-open-git-bash-here-context-menu-to-the-windows-explorer) very good answer for the context menu itself, but I don't want to clutter up my context menu with too many things that I don't use too often, so SendTo has become quite useful for me (after I delete all of the junk that Microsoft puts in there like 'Send to Bluetooth Device', and 'Send to Fax Machine' etc that no one ever uses). I've tried variations of `.lnk` in `shell:sendto` based on the above context menu answer like `C:\Program Files\GitPortable\git-bash.exe --cd=%1` but no luck so far.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916670/how-do-i-launch-a-git-bash-window-with-particular-working-directory-using-a-scri) link was suggested and I've painstakingly gone through every option there and none of them work for this. It sounds like this should be something simple with a simple solution (some combination of arguments in the Target field, and the `--cd` switch is almost certainly involved) but, so far, I have not found the secret sauce to make this work.

Comment: See that answer. You need to set the "start in" attribute of your shortcut. [How do I launch a Git Bash window with particular working directory using a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916670/how-do-i-launch-a-git-bash-window-with-particular-working-directory-using-a-scri)

Comment: Try `C:\Program Files\GitPortable\git-bash.exe --cd` as the shortcut target (without `=`). Selected items are appended with a space to the command-line. If this doesn't work, use a batch file to pass `%1` or a PowerShell script to pass `$args[0]` to `git-bash`.

Comment: Sadly, `--cd`, with or without the `=` does not make a shortcut that will open git in the right folder. I see your point that selected items get a space appended, that's important. Seems overkill to have to use a script for something as simple as this, but that may indeed be the case.